# Checking a Local PC ip address through cmd?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

How can I check an ip address of a computer through CMD which is on the same LAN as I am without any third party software?

I'm fully aware of pinging the PC name, but what would this problem below indicate?

```
C:\Users\Storage>ping malan-pc

Pinging Malan-PC [fe80::5cba:e518:d8df:ac30%12] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::5cba:e518:d8df:ac30%12: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::5cba:e518:d8df:ac30%12: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::5cba:e518:d8df:ac30%12: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::5cba:e518:d8df:ac30%12: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::5cba:e518:d8df:ac30%12:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: the address is not a MAC address but an ipv6 one. Try to force the ping on ipv4 (`ping hostname -4`)

Comment: Drop the [junk after the % sign](http://superuser.com/questions/99746/why-is-there-a-in-the-ipv6-address) and you have a perfectly valid IP address which you can use to connect to the remote system. IPv4 is going away sooner or later, so you may as well get used to IPv6 now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the IPv6 address. If you want the IPv4 address you need add -4 to the ping command.

```
ping -4 malan-pc
```

Answer (score 1):

This question really isn't for ServerFault, but I'll answer anyway

If DNS is working properly then simply "ping" the computer and look at the resolved IP.

I.e.

```
ping computername
```

And it should return something like

```
Pinging computername [172.16.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
```

Comment: I'm fully aware of what you stated above. See the following and please inform me of what the problem can be.

Comment: The OP actually followed your advice, but didn't then understand the output it gave him.  (Since it returned an IPV6 address)