# How can I add an IPv6 address with a scope ID to the ssh config file?

Tags: linux, ssh, ipv6

On Linux, an IPv6 address can have a scope ID at the end with a percent sign before it. For example: `fe80::1%usb0`. See [Why is there a percent sign '%' in the IPv6 address?](https://superuser.com/questions/99746/why-is-there-a-percent-sign-in-the-ipv6-address)

I want to add such an entry to my ssh config, but if I add `HostName fe80::1%usb0` to `~/.ssh/config`, I get an error:

```
percent_expand: unknown key %u
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to double the percent sign, like this:

```
Host vmiab
    HostName fe80::1%%usb0
```

[ssh-config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) has various substitutions such as `%h` and  `%l`, and if you want a literal percent sign it has to be escaped as `%%`.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are still trying to do proxy commands on the command line in zsh, here is an example of how to use it with ipv6 addresses

```
ssh -v -o "ProxyCommand sush -W \[%h\]:%p your_jump_server" your_user@aabb:aabb:aabb:aabb:aabb:aabb:aabb:0000
```

See how the `h` argument has now the escaped brackets but the ipv6 does not have any

Answer (score 1):

Beside the escaping of the percent sign, it can be necessary to enclose an ipv6 address into brackets `[]`.
It's necessary when the hostname is used by a ProxyCommand.

```
Host vmiab
    HostName [fe80::1%%usb]
    ProxyCommand ssh my_proxy_host -W %h:%p
```

Or you could enclose the host `[%h]` in the ProxyCommand (**prefered solution**)

```
Host vmiab
    HostName fe80::1%%usb
    ProxyCommand ssh my_proxy_host -W [%h]:%p
```

It's better to use the brackets in the ProxyCommand, because using brackets in the hostname only works with ProxyCommand, but fails without.

Comment: Note using brackets on the command line was rejected by OpenSSH: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1602

Comment: How to support IPv6 in HostName? In MacOS its failing with or without bracket

Comment: zsh:1: no matches found: [111b:c110:102:5477:0:2:0:3]:22
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host